# the phrase "its derivative" when a function has a derivative only almost everywhere

Tags: terminology, lebesgue-integral

Theorem: A function $F$ is an indefinite integral if and only if it is absolutely continuous

Corollary: Every absolutely continuous function is the indefinite integral of its derivative.
(thm 5.14,5.15 Royden,Real Analysis)

Since absolute continuity does not imply differentiability *everywhere* I am assuming that I could replace this with

"Every absolutely continuous function $F$ is the indefinite integral of any function $f$ which is equal to $F'$ almost everywhere",

and it is just assumed in analysis texts that the reader knows this?

Comment: You missed another infelicity: "the indefinite integral". That should be "an indefinite integral", surely? It looks as if this book was written in a hurry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is of course technically lazy. However, there is a way it makes sense! The issue here is that technically, the function has a derivative - but said derivative is defined in a space where "almost everywhere" is enough. The derivative is not (quite) a function in the traditional sense - its value is undefined on a set of measure 0.

The way to justify this has to do with the theory of [distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29) and of the integrable function spaces [$\mathcal{L}^p$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space). The derivative of any continuous (in fact, any locally integrable) function exists in a rigorous sense - it just may not be a function. In this case, what's being noted is that absolute continuity guarantees that the derivative of $f$ is "almost" a function, in the sense of being defined almost everywhere. In particular, this means it's well-defined in the space of integrable functions $\mathcal{L}^1$ - where functions are considered equivalent if they are equal almost everywhere.

Yes, this is a bit odd to wrap one's brain around - but it's a classic analyst's trick to "forget" for the moment that we're passing through a space in which functions are only defined up to changes on a set of measure 0.

EDIT: A quick clarification - what you state in the question, that $F$ is the integral of any function $f$ equal to $F'$ almost everywhere, is in fact ill-defined itself! After all, you're presuming that there's a function $F'$ to be equal to... you're passing through more general function spaces also, and just not noticing.

Comment: I don't state that $F^{'}$ is a function. Actually the question is "what if $F^{'}$ isn't a function.

Comment: OK, there is a lot to think about in EPAstor's answer. I'm surprised the texts (Royden's isn't the only one) assume you know this without mentioning these spaces. Maybe a pointless complaint, but I'm wary of assuming  an omission was made when it's in more than one text.                                                   I did find another text which states instead: "If $f$ is integrable on [a,b], then $F(x)=\int_a^xf(t)dt$ is differentiable almost everwhere, and $F^{'}(x)=f(x)$ almost everywhere." This is (to me) much more comprehensible and takes care of TonyK's comment too.

Answer (score 3):

If $f=g$ a.e. then $\int f=\int g$.

Comment: I realize that. It just seems odd that the corollary is stated with "its derivative" when it may not even have a derivative. Considering that mathematicians tend to be so particular about phrasing. So is your answer to my question yes?

Comment: I agree with Hagen.  In Royden's book, you have previously seen how to integrate a function defined almost everywhere; and that it doesn't matter how you extend the definition to everywhere.  Since it makes sense to integrate such an "almost everywhere" defined function, and the derivative we are talking about is such an "almost everywhere" defined function, there is no problem with the statement.